# R: Expand dataframe rows

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, expand

Given a 4x2 data frame such as:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
  X=c(1,3,6,10),
  Y=c('A','K','K3', 'K'))
```

I would like to get a 10x2 row dataframe were `X` is 1,2,...10 (like 1:10), and
`Y` is replicated the number of times specified in df$X, eg:

```
    X   Y
1   1   A
2   2   A
3   3   K
4   4   K
5   5   K
6   6   K3
7   7   K3
8   8   K3
9   9   K3
10  10  K
```

The only think I can think of is to build `Y` by looping through ´df´ like (pseudocode):

```
  for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
   Y <- c(Y,(rep.int(df$Y[i], df$X[i+1]-df$X[i])))}
```

It seems clumpsy. Maybe packages like `reshape2` or `splitstackshape` will help me?

Comment: You could also do `splitstackshape::expandRows(df, c(diff(df$X), 1), FALSE)` and then fix the `X` column or something

Comment: Or a base R option `transform(df[rep(1:nrow(df), c(diff(df$X),1)),], X= seq(max(df$X)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(X= min(df$X):max(df$X)) %>% 
         left_join(., df, by = "X") %>%
         fill(Y)
#    X  Y
#1   1  A
#2   2  A
#3   3  K
#4   4  K
#5   5  K
#6   6 K3
#7   7 K3
#8   8 K3
#9   9 K3
#10 10  K
```

Comment: Perfect. I forgot about tidyr.

Comment: Or `df %>% complete(X = full_seq(min(X):max(X), 1)) %>% fill(Y)`